# QGIS 3.0 and Qt 5.7 time schedule

Tags: qgis, qt

When will QGIS 3.0 with QT5.7 (possibly) be released as a stable and long term support version?

Comment: I installed Girona on Ubuntu 17.10 and it never worked for me.
I just updated Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Qgis displays the following message: Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, inImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.10 'not found (required by / home / user / .local / lib / python3.6 / site-packages / PyQt5 / QtCore.so) And it does not connect to the plugin repository. regards
Eduardo

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136939)

Answer (score 11):

According to the official [Road Map](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html#release-schedule)

- Qgis 3.0 was [released](http://blog.qgis.org/2018/02/23/qgis-3-0-girona-is-released/) on 2018-02-23.
- The first Long Term Support 3.x release will be version 3.4 on 2018-10-26.

Comment: For the moment, QGIS 3.0 is available with QT 5.5 for Ubuntugis xenial, plain ubuntu artful and bionic, and debian stretch and unstable.