# Are there any news about the release date of QGIS3

Tags: qgis

Since I will make a workshop on the new features of qgis 3, the members will ask the release date of QGIS3. 
Having a look to 
https://www.qgis.org/de/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html
only shows 2.18 until the next year, QGIS 3 has completly disapeard from the road map until 2019...?

Comment: [Very, very soon...](http://blog.qgis.org/2017/12/04/documentation-for-qgis-3-0-call-for-contributions/) hopefully :)

Comment: Seems they could not keep the Release on 2017-11-24 from their Road Map ;-) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253901/qgis-3-0-and-qt-5-7-time-schedule/253903#253903

Comment: https://www.qgis.org/de/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html says 2018-02-23

Answer (score 2):

No official release date confirmed yet.

Expected to be very soon.